# Strapi v3 filtering is not working as intended

Tags: node.js, strapi

I am trying to filter users by username like this `/users?username_containss=some@gmail.COM` and it gives me

```
[
  {
     ...
     email: "some@gmail.com",
     ...
  }
]
```

In the [stapi documentation](https://strapi.gitee.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/filters.html#available-operators), `containss` filter should be **case sensitive**, which should not give me this output.

**Note**: I try with other fields and its the same behaviour, i also try `/users?_where[0][email_containss]=some@gmail.COM` query and its the same result. Also if I use `ncontainss` with the same value it will give me other users except the one with that email in lowercase, which is not the desired output

Comment: You are right containss is for case sensitive use and the answer you get is wrong one. Please share the exact version of Strapi 3x you are using.

Comment: @CristianCimuca The strapi version is 3.6.5